# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when using up arrow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Microsoft visual studio whenever I press the up arrow in Code view, I get an error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is there a way to turn that error off or figure out why its displaying the message?

**Edit:**

I finally found a page related to my issue, however it did not fix my situation.

The error is within the IDE.. Its the same issue this guy was having (http://thejoyofcode.com/visual_studio_.net_datasources_bug.aspx), however I do not want to bind anything to my datagrid, I am loading the datagrid via a List<>

Anyway to turn this error off in VS2010?

Comment: Do you have more information? I believe there is a lot more in the error message.

Comment: Does it still happen after a restart of VS?? are you using any 3rd party addons??

Comment: I have no error in my code... its within the IDE.. Its the same issue this guy was having (http://www.thejoyofcode.com/visual_studio_.net_datasources_bug.aspx), however I do not want to bind anything to my datagrid, I am loading things via a List<>

Comment: I don't think its an error you can turn off, it sound more like a bug in visualStudio or one of the addons, (mind you it would be cool if you could turn bugs on and off :))

Comment: Definitely sounds like an add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Disable all add-ons
- Devenv /resetSettings
- Repair Visual Studio
- Uninstall & Reinstall Visual Studio (remove it via the MSICUU2 tool
  as well)
- Failing that rebuild OS

Comment: Restarting VS a few times seemed to do the trick..